# Как изменить заголовок Woocommerce исходя из выбранных атрибутов?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Всем привет!

Прошу помочь с решением моей задачи. Есть заголовок страницы товаров, который складывается из названия категории и выбранных атрибутов. Выбранные атрибуты зачастую не совсем логично отображаются. Мне нужно дополнить формулу - добавить условие для каких атрибутов прописать и название атрибута и значение атрибута, а для каких только значение атрибута.

Надеюсь понятно объяснил =)

Этот код делает примерно следующий вид заголовка:
"Категория + Заголовок атрибута 1 (1 значение, 2 значение, ...)", Заголовок атрибута 2 (1 значение, 2 значение, ...)":
Платья Пол (Для женщин),  Застежка (С пуговицами)

```
protected function formatAttributes($attributes)
    {
        $attributeStrings = [];
        /** @var FilterInterface $attribute */
        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
            $attribute->init();
            $items = $attribute->getActiveItems();
            $names = array_column($items, 'title');
            if (count($names)) {
                $attributeStrings[] = $attribute->getLabel() . ' (' . implode(', ', $names) . ')';

            }
        }

        return implode(', ', $attributeStrings);
    }
```

Мне нужен такой вид:
Платья для женщин с пуговицами

Я заметил, что если "getLabel" заменить на "init", то моя задача решается. Но тут подвох - не для всех атрибутов мне нужно удалить заголовки атрибута.

В итоге код должен быть примерно таким:
Если атрибут = Пол или Застежка, то не выводить заголовки атрибута, в остальных случаях выводить.

Можете подсказать, Что-то я совсем не догоняю.

Comment: Ай нид ХЭЭЭЭЭЛП =)

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется Вы сами ответили на свой вопрос!

Сделайте по условию:

```
if($attribute !== "Пол" || $attribute !== "Застежка")...
```

Также можно создать массив с правилами и проверять совпадения из массива с атрибутами.